# Opencv : Some clue to detect a word pointed by an index finger on an image

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, computer-vision

I just want to do a quick project on my spare time :

I take a photo (with my webcam) of a page of a book with my finger pointing at a word on the page. Something like that: [image]

I want to use opencv so I can isolate the word and translate it with OCR, etc ...

I cant' figure out exactly what to use in opencv to achieve this (I mean the "extraction" of the word in the complete photo), i read the tutorials but there is a lot of possibilities, so if someone can guide me by telling me what kind of functions do I need to use that would be kind :)

Thanks :)

Comment: There're a couple issues with your problem. One is uncertain conditions. For example you cover the word you're pointing at with your finger, which would make it hard to read. If you have a photo of the page without the finger, that will make taking a difference of images to fing finger possible. If you do have to rely on one image, that'll require different ways to solve it. You can build a model that will recognize your finger, but that's somewhat complicated. What i can recommend is looking into Hugh Transformation to find gaps between lines then words and looking for finger-like gap.